# Laravel Rest API Passport Conceptual Question

Tags: php, laravel, rest, user-permissions

I have worked on some previous Laravel projects, which were using Laravel as front- and backend solution. Most of them were just as simple as 1 user has 1 or more roles on 1 a single site.

Currently I am conceptional stuck on implementing roles and permission, for Laravel as a Rest API. NB. The frontend is running React on a different server, outside of Laravel's public folders.

I have a single users table, and these users can be assigned to projects, hence they can create them themselves. Within a project a user can have a different role. An admin on project A, can be an editor on B, and a reader on C, and so on.

Most RBAC/passport/permission packages I find, can assign multiple roles to users, so e.g. an editor and a writer. How could I add this small layer of abstraction, to get the project level scoped (even when working via the Rest API)? I feel I am missing something obvious here?

[image: Conceptional stupidity]

Comment: You can maybe manage project level permissions via an extra table like a user_project_permissions table? (It is advisable to use permissions to actually manage permissions. Use roles to group the permissions. So, always think about assigning permissions to users first. In generalised cases where you can manage permissions via roles, then it's okay to do so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages like [Laratrust](https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/docs/7.x/the-basics/teams.html) and [Spatie Laravel Permission](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/teams-permissions) packages offer Team based RBAC which might be worth investigating.

Another option would be to prefix your `roles` and `permissions` (it might not be a requirement to prefix permissions - `can_read` might be the same for all projects) with the name of the project they are associated to (i.e. `projectA_editor`, `projectB_admin`, `projectB_can_read`, `projectB_can_edit` etc.). Then use some logic (middleware) to perform checks against a `User`, their access level and the endpoint they are attempting to access.

Alternatively, you could adapt an existing package and create the logic for managing the project based access control (models and migrations etc.) providing associations between a `User`, `Project` and their access rights.

From an ease of implementation and management (package updates for example) I would be inclined to use the prefix option.

Comment: Thank you! Found a way to do this with prefixing permission in combination with Spatie Laravel Permission.